# Core data only storing last object of JSON feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, core-data

I´m using Core Data as local storage in my app. I´ve set it up properly and made subclasses of NSManagedObject for each entity. However, when I´m trying to insert values into my store, it only inserts the last object from my JSON feed.

```
res = [JSONHandler requestJSONResponse:jsonString];
shows = [res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.Name"];
NSUInteger showIndex = 0;
for(NSString *showName in shows){
    showObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Show" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
    showObject.name = showName;
    showObject.iD = [[res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.Id"]objectAtIndex:showIndex];
    showObject.desc = [[res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.Description"]objectAtIndex:showIndex];
    showObject.activityType = [[res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.ActivityType"]objectAtIndex:showIndex];

    showIndex++;
}
```

This only stores the last object from my JSON feed. Any idea why?

EDIT: It works fine when I do this:

```
res = [JSONHandler requestJSONResponse:jsonString];

shows = [res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.Name"];

NSUInteger index = 0;

for(NSString *showName in shows){
    show = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Show" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
    [show setValue:showName forKey:@"name"];
    [show setValue:[[res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.Id"]objectAtIndex:index] forKey:@"iD"];
    [show setValue:[[res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.Description"]objectAtIndex:index] forKey:@"desc"];
    [show setValue:[[res valueForKeyPath:@"Show.ActivityType"]objectAtIndex:index] forKey:@"activityType"];

    index++;
}
```

It´s basically the same thing, isn´t it? But I want to use subclasses of NSManagedObject instead of doing like I did above. Because in the snippet above show is NSManagedObject *show instead of what it should be: Show *show.

Comment: How does the JSON look? What is the result of `NSLog(@"Shows: %@", shows);`?

Comment: I´m 100% sure the JSON is fine.

Comment: What if you add the cast?  `showObject = (Show *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Show" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];`

Answer (score 0):

How many shows are there? You can find this by doing: `NSLog(@"Number of shows: %d.", shows.count);`, assuming that shows is an `NSArray`. It could be that your Core Data code is fine and the JSON parsing itself is at fault.

EDIT: Also, are you correctly saving the changes to the persistent store?

Comment: The count of shows is 42. What do you mean by correctly saving the changes to the persistent store?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you see just one of several objects being saved like this, the problem is that a relationship that should be to-many is improperly set as to-one. No matter how many objects you try to add to the relationship, only the last one is set because the relationship can hold only one value.

I think in this circumstance the problem is most likely in the code of the custom subclass instead of the data model itself given that the data model works with generic NSManagedObjects.